Associated Hermite polynomials
In quantum mechanics, one of the most common problems to solve is the quantum harmonic oscillator.
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}=\frac{1}{2}p^2+\frac{1}{2}x^2
\end{equation}
The most elegant way to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this Hamiltonian is by defining the annihilation and creation operators $a,a^{\dagger}$. The position operator is proportional to the $a+a^{\dagger}$ and its representation is given by the following infinite matrix
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&\sqrt{1}&0&0&\cdots\\
\sqrt{1}&0&\sqrt{2}&0&\cdots\\
0&\sqrt{2}&0&\sqrt{3}&\cdots\\
0&0&\sqrt{3}&0&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\
\end{pmatrix},
\qquad \text{bases}
\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
\left| 0\right\rangle\\
\left| 1\right\rangle\\
\left| 2\right\rangle\\
\left| 3\right\rangle\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\left| n\right\rangle$ denotes the $n-$th quantum state. The wavefunction of the $n-$th state is composed by a Gaussian distribution and a Hermitian polynomial.
\begin{equation}
\psi_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!}}e^{-x^2/2}H_n(x)
\end{equation}
Thus we know that the  eigenvalues of the position operator in this bases are all the reals numbers with eigenvectors given by the
\begin{align}
\left| x\right\rangle&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 
\left(
     \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(y-x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!}}e^{-y^2/2}H_n(y)dy
            \right)
\left| n\right\rangle
\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!}}e^{-x^2/2}H_n(x)
\left| n\right\rangle,\quad \text{eigenvalue}=x.
\end{align}
What happens when we do not consider the infinite matrix but only part of it?
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0&\sqrt{n+1}&0&0&\cdots&0\\
\sqrt{n+1}&0&\sqrt{n+2}&\cdots&0&0\\
0&\sqrt{n+2}&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&0&\sqrt{n+m}\\
0&0&0&\cdots&\sqrt{n+m}&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad \text{bases}
\quad
\left.\begin{pmatrix}
\left| n\right\rangle\\
\left| n+1\right\rangle\\
\left| n+2\right\rangle\\
\left| n+3\right\rangle\\
\vdots\\
\left| n+m-1\right\rangle\\
\left| n+m\right\rangle\\
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}(m+1) \text{dimensions}.
\end{equation}
I understand that the eigenvalues will be $(m+1)$ real numbers and that will always come in pairs. What I mean by that is that if $(m+1)$ is an even number then the eigenvalue will  be in the form $\pm e_j, j=1,2,\cdots,(m+1)/2$ and if $(m+1)$ is an odd number then the eigenvalues will be $0, \pm e_j, j=1,2,\cdots,m/2$. This is because the wavefunctions corresponding to these states are either odd or even functions. The coefficients in front of the odd functions decide in which part on the real line we are working on and by  changing the signs of the odd or the even function, we get to the other side. This means that if
\begin{equation}
\left| x_j\right\rangle=\sum_{m=n}^{n+m}c_m^{(j)}\left| m\right\rangle,
\quad\text{then}\quad
\left| -x_j\right\rangle=\sum_{m=n}^{n+m}(-1)^m c_m^{(j)}\left| m\right\rangle.
\end{equation}
For the same reason, I expect that when $m+1$ is an odd value, the eigenvector corresponding to the $0$ eigenvalue would be in the form
\begin{equation}
\left| x_j\right\rangle=\sum_{m}c_{2m}^{(j)}\left| 2m\right\rangle.
\end{equation}
We put all the coefficients of the odd functions equal to zero since the odd function  would put a "preferable" direction in the real line.  Apart from these facts, I thing that the wavefunctions can not offer me any other information. Am  I wrong?
To solve this problem, I tried to compute the eigenvalues in the "traditional" way. Finding the Characteristic polynomial $p$, then finding the roots and so one. This only works when $m+1\le4$. In general though I found a nice recurrence equation
\begin{equation}
p_{n+m}=-\lambda p_{n+m-1}-(n+m)p_{n+m-2},
\end{equation}
which is very similar with the Hermitian polynomials recurrence formula\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials}
\begin{equation}
H_{m+1}(x)=xH_{m}-(m)H_{m-1}.
\end{equation}
This means that if $n=0$, then $p_m=H_{m+1}(-\lambda)$ and thus the eigenvalues of the problem  are given by the nodes of the $H_{m+1}$ polynomial. Unfortunately, this does not help me very much in finding a closed form for the eigenvectors.
Is there a way to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this finite matrix, for all $n$ values? Are the solutions in any way correlated with the Hermitian polynomials when $n=0$?

You cannot just take a snippet of the energy eigenstates and hope to get position kets out of them. Your concept is just wrong. Quantum theory does not work that way.

The snip-projection operators you seek might be complicated.
